# Merging multiple CSV files into separate tabs of a spreadsheet in Python

Tags: python, excel, python-3.x, python-2.7, pandas

I have a code which generates multiple CSV files in a directory. I want to generate a report in excel which will consist of the CSV files as separate tabs.
I have used the below code for the same:

```
import pandas as pd
import os
import csv
import glob    
path = "/MyScripts"
all_files = glob.glob(os.path.join(path, "*.csv"))
df_from_each_file = (pd.read_csv(f) for f in all_files)
df_from_each_file.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='ReturnData.csv')
writer.save()
```

But it gives below error:
**AttributeError: 'generator' object has no attribute 'to_excel'**
Not sure where i am going wrong. Do i need to import any specific library to solve the issue?

**Python Version is 2.7**

Comment: You might want to look at xlswriter for merging serparate tabs of a spreadsheet. It provides more readability and easy to implement.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There are two issues here:

1. Your generator expression allows you to lazily iterate dataframe objects. You can't export a generator expression to an Excel file.
2. Your `sheet_name` parameter is a constant. To export to multiple worksheets, you need to specify a different name for each worksheet.

You can use a simple `for` loop for this purpose:

```
writer = pd.ExcelWriter('out.xlsx', engine='xlsxwriter')
df_from_each_file = (pd.read_csv(f) for f in all_files)

for idx, df in enumerate(df_from_each_file):
    df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='data{0}.csv'.format(idx))

writer.save()
```

Your worksheets will be named `data0.csv`, `data1.csv`, etc. If you need the filename as your sheet name, you can restructure your logic and use the `os` module to extract the filename from path:

```
import os

writer = pd.ExcelWriter('out.xlsx', engine='xlsxwriter')

for f in all_files:
    df = pd.read_csv(f)
    df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name=os.path.basename(f))

writer.save()
```

Comment: This was extremely useful. Thanks a ton @JPP

Comment: what is writer?

Comment: This doesn't work for me doesn't write anything

Comment: @Maths12, don't forget to save via `writer.save()`. See the [documentation](https://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.io/working_with_pandas.html).

Answer (score 6):

Here is the complete source code from jpp solution:

```
import os
import pandas as pd
import glob

path = './'
all_files = glob.glob(os.path.join(path, "*.csv"))

writer = pd.ExcelWriter('out.xlsx', engine='xlsxwriter')

for f in all_files:
    df = pd.read_csv(f)
    df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name=os.path.splitext(os.path.basename(f))[0], index=False)

writer.save()
```

Answer (score 0):

Although Python requires many fewer lines of code compared to VBA, I would probably use VBA for this kind of task.

```
' Merge data from multiple sheets into separate sheets
Sub R_AnalysisMerger2()
    Dim WSA As Worksheet
    Dim bookList As Workbook
    Dim SelectedFiles As Variant
    Dim NFile As Long
    Dim FileName As String
    Dim Ws As Worksheet, vDB As Variant, rngT As Range
    Dim vFn, myFn As String

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    SelectedFiles = Application.GetOpenFilename(filefilter:="Excel Files (*.csv*), *.csv*", MultiSelect:=True)
    If IsEmpty(SelectedFiles) Then Exit Sub

    For NFile = LBound(SelectedFiles) To UBound(SelectedFiles)
        FileName = SelectedFiles(NFile)
        vFn = Split(FileName, "\")
        myFn = vFn(UBound(vFn))
        myFn = Replace(myFn, ".csv", "")
        Set bookList = Workbooks.Open(FileName, Format:=2)
        Set WSA = bookList.Sheets(1)
        vDB = WSA.UsedRange
        bookList.Close (0)
        Set Ws = Sheets.Add(after:=Sheets(Sheets.Count))
        ActiveSheet.Name = myFn
        Ws.Range("a1").Resize(UBound(vDB, 1), UBound(vDB, 2)) = vDB
    Next
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub

' Merge data from multime files into one sheet.
Sub R_AnalysisMerger()
    Dim WSA As Worksheet
    Dim bookList As Workbook
    Dim SelectedFiles() As Variant
    Dim NFile As Long
    Dim FileName As String
    Dim Ws As Worksheet, vDB As Variant, rngT As Range

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False


    Set Ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1)
    Ws.UsedRange.Clear
    'change folder path of excel files here
    SelectedFiles = Application.GetOpenFilename(filefilter:="Excel Files (*.csv*), *.csv*", MultiSelect:=True)


    For NFile = LBound(SelectedFiles) To UBound(SelectedFiles)
        FileName = SelectedFiles(NFile)
        Set bookList = Workbooks.Open(FileName, Format:=2)
        Set WSA = bookList.Sheets(1)
        With WSA
            vDB = .UsedRange
            Set rngT = Ws.Range("a" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp)(2)
            If rngT.Row = 2 Then Set rngT = Ws.Range("a1")
            rngT.Resize(UBound(vDB, 1), UBound(vDB, 2)) = vDB

            bookList.Close (0)
        End With
    Next
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Ws.Range("A1").Select

End Sub
```

Answer (score -2):

you can user the pandas concate method

```
csv1 = pd.read_csv(csv1_file_path)
csv2 = pd.read_csv(csv2_file_path)

merge_csv = pd.concat((csv1, csv2), axis=0)
```

axis is user for merge in which directions